# Java Programm in Eclipse dodges captcha but executable JAR doesn't

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, captcha

I'm writing a java application that does HTTP requests to a website in Eclipse:

- Login in with basic auth
- Website has Captcha for logins
- Captcha can be bypassed if you recently logged in with the browser

The problem is that since I exported my application to an executable JAR the bypass doesn't work anymore. It only works in Eclipse.
Is it possible to bypass the captcha with the executable JAR aswell?

Comment: We'll need a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you run the jar from the command line in order to see any stacktraces? A resource file in a jar is case-sensitive and uses a `/` instead of a `\` under Windows.

Comment: I did not run in from the command line. And sorry but, what do you mean by "stacktraces" and "ressource file in a jar" ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there would be some cookies set in the browser, after a successful login. On subsequent logins, these would be sent to the website, to detect and not show the captcha. Once you moved the call to a jar, the cookies are missing, so it will not work.

**recommendation to fix**

check if any cookies are set in the browser, after successful login. Set the same cookies in the request made from the jar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look into that. Seems like a pretty difficult task. Especially because I am trying to make the program as automatic as possible.